# Angular-only TreeView

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, treeview

I am looking for a way to display a treeview using angular.

I cannot figure out how to make one using Angularjs by itself, as it seems to not have a native treeview.

The basic requirements would be the ability to select parent values as well as children values and the table setup I have currently is as follows:

```
ItemLocationID
ParentLocationID
Description
```

I also have a setup for if it is requiring to be setup with Children then it is

```
ItemLocationID
ParentLocationID
Description
Children /'contains items that have ParentLocationIDs = this items ItemLocationID'/
```

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

To further explain what I am trying to accomplish, I will give a better example of my layout.

I am trying to add this list to a table for the user to select an items location. Most items already have an item location set up and I would like the list to auto-select the correct location based on this value.

I would also like for it to be minimizable (Similar to a combobox) or only show the selected value (which can be swapped between it and the tree via a button or similar action)

The following images hopefully show what I am desiring

[Collapsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkmOo.png)
[Expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuM39.png)

Comment: https://github.com/eu81273/angular.treeview

Comment: I have attempted to use this solution, but it is not working for me. The  

angular.module('app', ["angularTreeview"]); 

part of the code doesn't work for me and causes me to lose all angular components of my project.

Comment: add it to the the modules array. e.g. do `angular.module('app',['angularTreeview', 'myOtherModule1', ...])` instead of replacing it with `angular.module('app', ["angularTreeview"])`

Comment: Alright! I have this working, to some extent, but is there a way to have it "pre-select" a value based on a value in a table? For example, I have rows of items and the item's location is set via the ItemLocationID. I want the user to only see the ItemLocationDescription for the ItemLocationID selected, but be able to change it via this tree. I will edit my question to reflect this additional requirement.